# Why does Python's CONTINUE_LOOP allow an outer loop, when BREAK_LOOP doesn't?

Tags: python, loops, bytecode, cpython, python-internals

I've noticed an intriguing peculiarity in Python's bytecode [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-BREAK_LOOP).

The `CONTINUE_LOOP` opcode takes in a `target` argument that denotes the instruction of the loop to continue executing, which is a `FOR_ITER` instruction.

The `BREAK_LOOP` opcode, however, does not do this. It only breaks out of the current (innermost) loop.

What is the reason behind this? Why should it be possible to `continue` but not `break` an outer loop?

Comment: Such inconsitencies are most of the time due to the evolution of the code. But it's just my guess.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are misunderstanding the target. The value is not needed to handle nested loops. Instead, the target marks the point in the bytecode stream to move to after the instruction. `BREAK` doesn't need such a target because that value is already defined elsewhere.

`BREAK_LOOP` ends a loop and thus execution continues *after* the loop. The [`SETUP_LOOP` instruction](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-SETUP_LOOP) has defined the endpoint already, so the interpreter doesn't need any additional information to execute this opcode.

`CONTINUE_LOOP` on the other hand needs to be told where to continue to. In most loops, a [`JUMP_ABSOLUTE` opcode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-JUMP_ABSOLUTE) is used, and `CONTINUE_LOOP` echoes that instruction here. `CONTINUE_LOOP` records a bit more information to handle `try` statements (to track stack unwinding).

In the evaluation loop, exception handling (`try: ... except:` and `try
: ... finally:`) as well as context managers (`with ...:` and `async with ...:`) use a generalised concept of a *frame block*, which has an exit point recorded for it, which is what the `BREAK_LOOP` instruction relies on here. Not having to track an offset is simpler this way and avoids the compiler and evaluation loop having to repeat themselves (the exit point is used for other scenarios too, not just the `break` statement).

But jumps are more generic and so their offsets are easier to track tied to the instruction itself.

Comment: I felt like I understood for a moment but now I feel like I don't really understand. `CONTINUE_LOOP` can only jump to one location: the first loop instruction. If `SETUP_LOOP` has already specified where the loop is, then doesn't the interpreter know how to re-enter it the same way it would know how to exit it? After all, it is told the loop extents already, right?

Comment: @Mehrdad: you need to store the jump target *somewhere*. `JUMP_ABSOLUTE` and `CONTINUE_LOOP` store it as an offset with the opcode. That's easier to manage than to have the evaluation loop track all possible loop-related values all the time.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I mean then why doesn't that argument apply to `BREAK_LOOP` just the same? Isn't it easier to manager if it's right there instead of the interpreter having to track it?

Comment: @Mehrdad: Loops, `except` and `finally` blocks are handled the same, so the frame block object for them has been generalised; they all use an exit offset. Using this setup simplified the evaluation loop code.

Comment: Hmmmm... they could just as easily have added the enter offset too though. Not exactly the most convincing but it's definitely better than nothing. +1 Thanks~

Comment: @Mehrdad: so why repeat yourself? You need that exit offset for *other things too*, not just the break statement.

Comment: You don't need to do this for anything but a `for` loop though. All you need to do is push the block entrance offset when you see `FOR_ITER` (*not* when you see `SETUP_LOOP`; that's only good for the exit offset). You can leave it uninitialized otherwise. It wouldn't add a *single* cycle to the handling of `try`/`except`/`finally` or slow down anything at all, right?

Comment: @Mehrdad: it still adds overhead, you now have a permanent offset to track for all loops, even if they never iterate. A single value to track that the compiler and evaluation loop now need to know about. You already have well-tested handling of opcode argument values and offsets, adding this complication is *just not worth it*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: OK -- but then why push the exit offset on `SETUP_LOOP` when there might not be a `BREAK_LOOP` or the loop might not even iterate either? By the same logic, you should leave the block exit offset uninitialized for loops, since -- *just like* the entrance offset -- it's an extra value that you have to permanently track for all loops, even if they never iterate. Am I missing something?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I imagine the counterargument is that you have to push the exit offset anyway, because you have to know where the loop block ends, for whatever reason (e.g. if an exception is thrown). But then I don't get how that's useful if you don't also keep trace of where the loop block begins, since you'd need it to figure out which block you're currently in. And if you do keep track of that, then what's the point of requiring it to be re-specified! etc.

Comment: OH, here's an idea. Knowing where the loop block begins doesn't tell you where the `FOR_ITER` is, since the number of instructions between `SETUP_LOOP` and `FOR_ITER` isn't fixed. So you'd still need to write something on `FOR_ITER`. Is this correct? If so then this would make sense, I think.

Comment: @Mehrdad: because the iterator exits from the top. When `for` iterable is exhausted or the `while` test fails, at which point you want to know the jump offset *too*. You **always** have to exit the loop from the top instruction. For `try` blocks, you need to know where to jump to when exiting the block via an exception. So those exit points are used all the time, and the generalisation makes the evaluation loop simpler and easier to follow. You don't need to know where the block begins for either of these.

Comment: Ohh, duh. Forgot about the obvious there :) okay that makes sense, thanks a ton!

Comment: @Mehrdad: (and that `FOR_ITER` can appear *without `SETUP_LOOP`* when using a list comprehension doesn't really matter in all this).